# $\exists f \in L^1(X, \mu)$ such that $\int_X g d \nu = \int_X g \cdot f d\mu \text{ for all } g \in L^{\infty} (X, \mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\nu: \mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a signed measure and $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite. Show that there is a function $f \in L^1(X, \mu)$ such that $\int_X g d \nu = \int_X g \cdot f d\mu \text{ for all } g \in L^{\infty} (X, \mu)$

My thought: we have to use Kamtorovitch Representation Theorem: For $\nu \in BFA(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ define: $T_{\nu}: L^{\infty}(X, \mu)\to \mathbb{R}$ by $T_{\nu}(f)=\int_Xf d\nu $ for all $f\in L^{\infty}(X, \mu)$. Then $T$ is an isometric isomorphism of the normed linear space $BFA(X, \mathcal{M},\mu)$onto the dual of $L^{\infty}(X, \mu)$(where $BFA(X, \mathcal{M},\mu)$ we denote the normed linear space of bounded finitely additive signed measures $\nu$ on $\mathcal{M}$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ in the sense that if $E \in \mathcal{M}$ and $\mu(E)=0$ then $\nu(E)=0$)

Any help with this problem?

Comment: Hint: If a measure $\nu$ is given by $\nu(A)=\int_A fd\mu$, then $\int_X gd\nu=\int_X gfd\mu$ for all $g\geq 0$.

Comment: ok, we can use simple approximation lemma and monotone convergence theorem to prove your hint, how is this help next?

Comment: What you want to show is false if you do not assume $\nu(A)=0$ if $\mu(A)=0$.